# webasyst не видит содержимое POST

Tags: php

В функции, ответственной за сохранение, в логах не пишет, что файл загружен, хотя все остальные данные на месте. В чем может быть дело?

```
public function saveSettings($settings = array()) {

    $check = $this->getSettings('offer_icon_1');
    error_log($check, 0);
    $data = waRequest::post();
    error_log(serialize($data), 0);
    error_log(serialize($settings), 0);
    $image = waRequest::file('offer_icon_1');

    error_log($image, 0);


    $id = 1;
    $model = new offers_iconsModel();
    $model->updateById($id, array('name' => 'hwwwelddlo', 'path' => 'yoyo'));

    paren
```

t::saveSettings($settings);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем файлы не передаются без контроллера своего, однако, это все равно можно обойти. Нужно было влепить:

```
<script>
    $.plugins.options.useIframeTransport = true;
</script>
```

в шаблон settings.html

и файлы стали нормально передаваться